# What's wrong with my JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried this code, which worked the first time. But for some reason it didn't work after. I don't get it.

The code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#blue").mouseenter(function(){    
        $("#pink").slideDown("normal", function(){    
            $("#green").animate({width:'toggle'});
        });
    });
    $("#green").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#green").animate({width:'toggle'}, function(){
            $("#pink").slideUp();
        });
    });
});
```

What I'm trying to do is have one slide event for when you hover to and from the designated area. This seems to malfunction for reasons that I'm not sure.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vL65X/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vL65X/ is working fine!!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/vL65X/2/

Comment: no. it goes haywire with my mouse still pointed at the box. The animation seems to keep going when my mouse remains on the box.EDIT: Seems to be a problem with my browser. The regular code is working perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: hello again. I just closed my Firefox 27.0.1 and restarted the browser. The code works fine now. This is so strange. Anyhow, I'm going to take Jorg's cue and use stop functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animations get queued. Try using [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) or [.clearQueue()](https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)...

edit: looked up the doco.

```
$("#blue").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#pink").stop().slideDown("normal", function(){
    $("#green").stop().animate({width:'toggle'});
        });     
    });
$("#green").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#green").stop().animate({width:'toggle'}, function(){
    $("#pink").stop().slideUp();
        });     
    });
```